# Soft delete: Copy row data to archive table when deleting

Tags: mysql, trigger

How can I move data from my current table to an archive table when a delete is called on the table?

My current table and archive table needs to be in sync in their schema too.

Can someone help me?

**Edit**:
I am using **MySql**

Answer (score 4):

*(This answer is assuming SQL Server)*

```
-- create the audit table
select *
into YourTableDeleteAudit
from YourTable
where 1 = 2
go

-- create the trigger
create trigger YourTableDeletes
on YourTable
after delete
as
    insert into YourTableDeleteAudit
    select *
    from deleted
go
```

This would result in an audit table of a copy of the deleted records.  I would recommend putting a `datetime` stamp on that (and maybe more fields for typical auditing).  You could do that like this:

```
-- create the audit table
select *
into YourTableDeleteAudit
from YourTable
where 1 = 2
go

alter table YourTableDeleteAudit
add DeleteDate datetime null
go

-- create the trigger
create trigger YourTableDeletes
on YourTable
after delete
as
    insert into YourTableDeleteAudit
    select *, getdate()
    from deleted
go
```

Comment: Another option in SS is to use the `OUTPUT` clause in the `DELETE` statement to archive in one step.

Comment: What about RI that would be referencing the original table?